# Put a title above a matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I have the following code, which draws a title (`a matrix:`) and a `matrix`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle,draw=black}, nodes in empty cells]
  \node at (0,2) {\Large a matrix:};
  \matrix[
  matrix of math nodes,
  row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={anchor=center, minimum width=2cm, cell},
  column 1/.style = {nodes={minimum width=2cm}},
  column 2/.style = {nodes={minimum width=2cm}},
  row 1/.style = {nodes={text height=1.3ex, text depth=0}},
  ] 
  { 123 & 456  \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

A problem of this code is that if I put more rows in the matrix, the coordinate of the title `(0,2)` will not be suitable any more.

So is it possible to put the title in a flexible position no matter what the height and width of the matrix are? I just want to put it in the middle and above the matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a label to the matrix and draw the node with reference to it like

```
\node[font=\Large,anchor=south] at (m.north) {a matrix:};
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle,draw=black}, nodes in empty cells]
  \matrix[
  matrix of math nodes,
  row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={anchor=center, minimum width=2cm, cell},
  column 1/.style = {nodes={minimum width=2cm}},
  column 2/.style = {nodes={minimum width=2cm}},
  row 1/.style = {nodes={text height=1.3ex, text depth=0}},
  ](m)
  { 123 & 456  \\
  123 & 456  \\
  123 & 456  \\
  123 & 456  \\
  123 & 456  \\
  };
  \node[font=\Large,anchor=south] at (m.north) {a matrix:};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A `matrix` is a `node`. Knowing that a simple `label` can be used to add labels to nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle,draw=black}, nodes in empty cells]
  \matrix[
  matrix of math nodes,
  row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={anchor=center, minimum width=2cm, cell},
  column 1/.style = {nodes={minimum width=2cm}},
  column 2/.style = {nodes={minimum width=2cm}},
  row 1/.style = {nodes={text height=1.3ex, text depth=0}},
  label={[font=\large]above:a matrix:}   %<--------------------
  ](m)
  { 123 & 456  \\
  123 & 456  \\
  123 & 456  \\
  123 & 456  \\
  123 & 456  \\
  };
%  \node[font=\Large,anchor=south] at (m.north) {a matrix:};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]